# Vaadin populating a Grid from SQLContainer

Tags: java, sql, vaadin

I need help with populating a Grid with data from a SQLContainer. I have the following code:

```
 public void createConnetionDB(){
            try {
                connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                         "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                         "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root", 2, 5);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                text.setCaption(e.toString()); 

            }
      }

public SQLContainer initSQLContainer(){
   TableQuery tq = null; 
   tq = new TableQuery("articles", connectionPool);
   tq.setVersionColumn("OPTLOCK");
   SQLContainer articleContainer  = new SQLContainer(tq);

   return articleContainer; 

}

Grid articles = new Grid(); 
articles.setContainerDataSource(initSQLContainer());
```

I get nullpointerexception when running this. Whats wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace ?

Comment: Where are you calling `createConnetionDB` ?

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception cause the variable `connectionPool` is `null`. I think you forgot to call `createConnectionDB()`.

Try it like this:

```
public SQLContainer initSQLContainer() {

   createConnetionDB();  

   TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("articles", connectionPool);
   tq.setVersionColumn("OPTLOCK");
   SQLContainer articleContainer  = new SQLContainer(tq);

   return articleContainer; 

}
```